# How to call method defined in Gradle Plugin in Consumer?

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm still new in developing Gradle Plugin. But what i want to do is to define global method to call in consumer gradle file.

So my plugin class looking something like this:

```kotlin
class Main : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        // Some configuration
    }

    fun modulePath(moduleName: String, target: Project): Any {
        val propFile = File("${target.rootDir}/local.properties")
        if (!propFile.exists()) propFile.createNewFile()
        val props = Properties()
        props.load(propFile.inputStream())

        val useAAR = props.getProperty("useAAR", "false")?.toBoolean() ?: false
        val devModule = props.getProperty("modules", ":app").split(" ")

        return if (useAAR && !devModule.contains(moduleName)) {
          "$groupId:$moduleName:$versionId"
        } else {
           target.project(moduleName)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val groupId = "local"
        const val versionId = "0.1"
    }
}
```

I can apply the plugin just fine in the consumer. But I still don't know how to call `modulePath` method in consumer's gradle file. Something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'main'


dependencies {
 implementation modulePath(':someModule')
}
```

When i'm calling the `modulePath`, i'm getting error that the method is not defined.

Thanks in advance.